# Why is my full text search not working in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

Table columns:

[image]

Table data:

[image]

Full text index definition:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_FULLTEXT_WorkOrder ON WorkOrder(ID);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON WorkOrder (Description)
KEY INDEX IDX_FULLTEXT_WorkOrder
ON full_text_catalog;
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[WorkOrder]
WHERE CONTAINS([Description],  '"Priorité 8"')
```

Incorrect result: The 9 (all) rows of my table, instead of the single one corresponding to my query.

Also why is that query (notice the * character):

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[WorkOrder]
WHERE CONTAINS([Description],  '"Priorité 8*"')
```

not returning any result at all (0)?

Comment: For the first part, I'm not sure why it's returning all rows, but I don't think you need the double quotes. I could be wrong. I'd try `CONTAINS([Description],  'Priorité 8')` For the last part, removing the 8  I would expect to return all rows. You are stating that you want to return all rows which **start** with Priorite 8. Since SQL Server generally ignores trailing spaces, even if you had them this threshold likely wouldn't matter. Lastly, I would expect you would want Description to be `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` unless your column is guaranteed to be constrained.

Comment: What gets returned if you have `CONTAINS([Description],  ' Priorité AND 8 ')`

Comment: @scsimon `CONTAINS([Description], 'Priorité 8')` gives an error: Syntax error near '8' in the full-text search condition 'Priorité 8'.

Comment: @WEI_DBA `WHERE CONTAINS([Description],  'Priorité AND 8')` returns 0 rows

Comment: I see, the double quotes are necessary because of the space. Something not usual in sql but is specific to contains and some other functions.